# How do I set icons and description of file types associated with Notepad++?

Tags: icons, notepad++, file-types

I tried using Nirsoft's File Type Manager to change the icons and file descriptions of individual file types associated with Notepad++. However, if I change the icon of one file type, all of the other file types associated with Notepad++ also change. How can I make each file type have a different icon?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change it for individual file types one by one. Please check this http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-file-type-icon-windows-7-vista/ 
Be careful while editing registry since it can cause boot failure. Make sure you have back ups too.