# Change description of file types associated with Notepad++

Tags: windows-8, notepad++, file-association

I recently installed Notepad++ v6.6.6 (On Windows 8 x64) and associated file types. The installer changed file type description of every associated extension to **Notepad++ Document**.

For example, I have **php**, **css** and **js** files in the same folder it groups all files under **Notepad++ Document**. Is there any way to change file type descriptions to their default. Like:

- php - PHP File or PHP Script
- css - CSS File or Cascading Stylesheet
- js  - JS File or JavaScript Document

I tried **FileTypesMan** but when I change description of 1 file type it changes all file type description. For example, when I change **txt** file to **Text Document** it changes all ext. associated with notepad++ to **Text Document**  .

I'm willing to change every file type description by hand.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: Mine looked like this after I set notepad++ to be the default handler for those file types so I'm guessing you're talking about something else or maybe the windows 8.1 updates have fixed whatever you're having an issue with. Image of what I'm talking about: http://i.imgur.com/kMg7DiP.png

Comment: @Codezilla Here is my screenshot ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UIaSdYG.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set icons and description of file types associated with Notepad++?](http://superuser.com/questions/378643/how-do-i-set-icons-and-description-of-file-types-associated-with-notepad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\UserChoice\ProgId
```

You should see something like `Notepad++_file`

If you find the entry for that in HKCR, e.g.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notepad++_file
```

You'll see the description "Notepad++ Document", this is where Explorer picks it up from. If you simply set the value for `Notepad++_file` to empty and then ALL files will revert to generic descriptions, e.g. TXT file, PHP file etc.

Comment: You might have to restart your computer for this to take effect. I had to on Windows 10.